# В mysql какой тип ячейки выбрать, если загружаемых данных может быть и число и буквы для одной и той же колонки?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, запрос

В загружаемых данных могут попасться суммы денег вида 1000034, а в некоторых случаях попадается смесь цифр и букв, например, 23XXX. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой тип ячейки в таблице выбрать для такой колонки? Надо ли мне в запросе INSERT 23XXX брать в кавычки? А цифры нет?

Заранее спасибо за любой совет!

Comment: Очевидно, что `varchar`. При таком типе `колонки` - все значение нужно брать в кавычки.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!